# Sequelize Connection Timeout

Tags: typescript, postgresql, express, transactions, sequelize.js

I am facing one strange error suddenly. While It was working fine last week, suddenly it is giving me errors like "Operation Timeout" or "SequelizeConnectionAqquireTimeout". Below are my sequelize connection settings. I am using typescript with sequelize.

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize(DATABASE_URL, {
dialect: 'postgres',
logging: +ENABLE_LOG === 1 && logger.info.bind(null, '\n%s'),
pool: {
  max: 5,
  min: 0,
  acquire: 30000,
  idle: 10000,
},
dialectOptions: {
  idle_in_transaction_session_timeout: 1000,
  application_name: `My Project - ${NODE_ENV}`,
},
```

});

I tried to increase acquire and idle time. but no luck. i also increased **shared_buffers** & **max_connections**. still no luck. I am seeing a red session in my pgAdmin. As soon as I start the server, I face the same error. There are hardly one or two users accessing it at the time as we are developing it. I am also using "**Citus**" database extension.

below is a screenshot from my pgAdmin Dashboard from the database.

[image]

Is there any way to debug this or find out what is causing this? There is no or minimum traffic. And there is not much data on data.

Note: On the same database server, other applications using other databases running fine without any issues.